# how to uninstall php 7.0 from Web PI in IIS 8.5

Tags: php, iis

How to manually remove php 7.0 from IIS 8.5 on Windows Server 2012R2?

I have installed WPI on IIS 8.5 and downloaded php 5.6 & 7.0 but I dont want php 7.0 and PHPManager is not available for  IIS 8.5

Is there any other solution?

Comment: You might want to ask this on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) instead

Comment: Control Panel | Programs. Nothing special.

Comment: I've installed it from Web Platform Installer 5.0. And php7.0 is not in my Control Panel | Program list

Answer (score 4):

Actually [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435479/3186326) answer is correct. I just want to add detail steps;

1. Open IIS and select Server which are using php cgi
2. Select Handler Mappings remove php handlers
3. Select FasCGI and remove Php CGI path
   [image]
4. Just delete all installation folder (default in C:\Php or C:\Program Files)
5. Also you should remove the Php from your System env. Path Variable
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Just got the solution:
Go to Handler Mappings ad uninstall whichever version you want to!
Then delete the Php file from C:/Program Files